# yii\base\ErrorException - Class 'app\controllers\EntryForm' not found

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I just tried the [Working with Forms](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-forms.html) tutorial on the "basic" version of Yii v 2.0.0. I followed it step by step, but I guess something is wrong. I have the EntryForm model in place, SiteController has the actionEntry and both the views are there too.

Error Trace:

```
1. in /usr/share/nginx/html/basic/controllers/SiteController.php at line 99

}

public function actionAbout()
{
    return $this->render('about');
}

public function actionEntry()
{
    $model = new EntryForm;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        // valid data received in $model

        // do something meaningful here about $model ...

        return $this->render('entry-confirm', ['model' => $model]);
    } else {
        // either the page is initially displayed or there is some validation error

2. yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleFatalError()
```

Comment: Did you include your `entryform` model in your `sitecontroller`?

Comment: Coming from Yii 1.1.15 I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`use app\models\EntryForm;` in SiteController.php solved it.

Comment: or `use common\models\EntryForm` if your model lives under `common`

Comment: Thanks he never mention it in the tutorial. I was stuck on this part too.

Answer (score 3):

The base namespace in SiteController.php is *namespace app\controllers;*.
So you can add *use app\models\EntryForm;* in the top of file or use *$model = new  \app\models\EntryForm();* for direct select of class.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve my issue by generation a different table using Gii. Then the auto generated class and used it on EnterForm.php

class EntryForm extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord